# Navbar mobile not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

**I have a simple navbar:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> 
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="navBtn" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="ion-android-menu"></span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"> Home</i> </a>
              </li>                 
          </ul>
      </div>
 </nav>
```

**And 2 scripts:**

```
<script>
    $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function () {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        $("#navBtn").attr('aria-expanded', false);
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {  
        var container = $(".collapse");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
           // $(".collapse").slideUp();
            // remove class
            $("#navBtn").attr('aria-expanded', false);
            $("#navbarSupportedContent").removeClass("show");
        }

    }); 
</script>
```

What I want is that the sandwich menu (as they call those 3 horizontal stacked stripes) closes when clicked on the X (once it's opened). It open's fine and when clicked everywhere outside the menu, it closes. But when clicked on the X it closes but imediately reopens ...

What can I do to achieve this? I have no errors in the console (inspect element) and I have tried tweaking the add/remove class and analyzed the behavior in the inspect element but I don't know why this happens ...
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
As suggested by DCR I have know used the Toggle() function but I still can't make it work, it's either closing and reopening or closing but the X is staying instead of switching to the stripes or a mix of those combinations ...

I have this now:

```
<script>
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".collapse");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            // remove class
            $("#navbarSupportedContent").removeClass("show");    
            $("#navBtn").attr('aria-expanded', false);
        }
        else {
            $("#navbarSupportedContent").toggle();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: don't use hide and show, rather use a toggle. When you click if it's open close, and if closed open.  Check jquery for their toggle function or write your own

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 you'll find the correct way to toggle the "collapse" on https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this @DCR, can you look at my editted post and advise me what is wrong?

Comment: When I double click the menubutton, it closes, 1 click close-reopens it. I don't understand this anymore ...

Comment: @bron, this works for me but when I try to combine both as in my edit example it doesn't close anymore unless i doubleclick the X menu button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, the method `.collapse("hide")` will hide the collapsable part.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> 
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="navBtn" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="ion-android-menu"></span> </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"> Home</i> </a>
      </li>                 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When clicking outside the menu, for example on an X that is not in the menu, the div will collapse with the "hide" property in .collapse()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function (event) {
    var Click = $(event.target);
    var Opend = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("show");
    if (Opend === true && !Click.hasClass("navbar-toggler")) {
      $("#navbarSupportedContent").collapse("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @bron, will try this tonight and post back here!

Comment: Suc6 with your Bootstrap website.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#navBtn').click(function () {
        $(".navbar-collapse").toggle();
        let ariaExpanded = ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true');
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded',!ariaExpanded);
});
    
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {  
        let container = $(".navbar");
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $("#navBtn").attr('aria-expanded', false);
            $(".navbar-collapse").hide();
        }

    });
```

```css
.navbar-collapse {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> 
      <button onclick="//myFunction()" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="navBtn" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="ion-android-menu">Toggle navigation</span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li>
                  <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'><i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"> Home</i> </a>
              </li>                 
          </ul>
      </div>
 </nav>
```

You can use the .toggle() on the button to show and hide the nav. When you click elsewhere in the doc, you can just hide the nav. I added a little CSS in my example after guessing at what yours might be.

Comment: it doens't hide the nave when clicked on the button, that is my issue. However, thank you for the effort and the code, it's better/cleaner than mine. Do you know how to also make it close the nav when clicked the button again?

Comment: @Dimitri - I edited it; it closes the navbar now. The underlying issue is that BOTH the button click and the other document.click were firing and toggling the navbar twice in rapid succession. We needed to change the check to see if you were not just on the navigation but also on the button.

Comment: thank you! Will check this tonight and get back to you!

Comment: Something is off, when I open/close with the button everything is good. Only when the menu is open and I click outside of the container, it closes fine and the X becomes the menu stripes again but from there on, when clicking on the button again, it pops open very quick, closes and reopens (open-close-stays open), not having the X but the stripes while being open, I then need to close it by clicking outside of the container (not with the btn) otherwise it always opens 2times (open-close-stays open) and the icons (stipes/X) are switched ... Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: @Dimitri, I am not seeing this behavior in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: in firefox, I will test in chrome tonight and post feedback! (Thank you very much so far!)

Comment: If I could I would take both as answer because you helped me a lot and made me understand more as well so thank you for that! bron's answer worked for me. I'm not good at CSS-JS I'm more of a backend guy but thank you both so much for your help and effort!